# Html element shifts to right when clicked - css issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

I am using jquery popup for displaying extra information to user.
There is one link in the page, on click of that, I am displaying the popup from upper side.

I am using popup of [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/GAIkt)
Now the issue is when I click on that link, it moves to right side.

This issue comes into the picture when content of the page is more and vertical scrollbar appears.

When content fits into the page, no such issue arised.

html code is as below.

file: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>CodePen - Pen</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://dimsemenov-static.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/magnific-popup.css'>

    <style>
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* text-based popup styling */
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 25px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* 

====== Move-from-top effect ======

*/
.mfp-move-from-top {
  /* start state */
  /* animate in */
  /* animate out */
}
.mfp-move-from-top .mfp-content {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.mfp-move-from-top .mfp-with-anim {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
.mfp-move-from-top.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.mfp-move-from-top.mfp-ready .mfp-with-anim {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.mfp-move-from-top.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.mfp-move-from-top.mfp-removing .mfp-with-anim {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.mfp-move-from-top.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* preview styles */
html {
  font-family: "Calibri", "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}

a,
a:visited {
  color: #1760BF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #c00;
}

.links li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h4 {
  margin: 24px 0 0 0;
}

.bottom-text {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-top: 2px solid #CCC;
}
.bottom-text a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.bottom-text p {
  max-width: 650px;
}

</style>

  <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<center><h1>Web Assistant</h1></center>


            <p>
                Page Content 1
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>

            <p>
                Page Content 2
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Page Content 3
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Page Content 4
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>

            <p>
                Page Content 5
            </p>
            <br>
            <br><p>
                Page Content 6
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Page Content 7
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Page Content 8
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Page Content 9
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Page Content 10
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
<div   id="inline-popups" class="links" style="position:fixed; top:90%; right:5%;">
    <a href="#test-popup" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top">See Help</a>
</div>


<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide">You may put any HTML here. This is dummy copy. It is not meant to be read. It has been placed here solely to demonstrate the look and feel of finished, typeset text. Only for show. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed.</div>

  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://dimsemenov-static.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

code of index.js file is as below.

```
// Inline popups
$('#inline-popups').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a',
  removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
  callbacks: {
    beforeOpen: function() {
       this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
    }
  },
  midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
});
```

Comment: set up a fiddle on jsfiddle.  It would make it easier to debug

Answer (score 9):

This is something that Magnific Popup is doing.  It sets a `margin-right` of `17px` on the `html` element. I'm not sure why, although I've read on GitHub that it is a fix for something. Anyways, you could fix with the following CSS:

```
html {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: The only fix that worked across all browsers, and I've tried quite a few for the past couple of hours. Many thanks!

Comment: @Andrei You're welcome! I struggled with this too so I figured I'd share.

Answer (score 2):

On the `body` set `overflow-y: scroll`. This way the space for the scrollbar is always reserved, even when there is no need for a scrollbar.

Comment: No it didn't solved,
now 2 scrollbars I am getting on page,
one is the original one, which was displaying before,
and one extra, that is added when I set overflow-y:scroll to the <body> tag.

It didn't solved the peroblem..